# Rак вывести в цикле несколько страниц по указанным id? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как вывести в рандомном порядке 3 страницы из перечисленных id?
Id страниц 6314, 6311, 6308, 6304, 6301, 6297.
get_posts(include) не подойдет, так как при его использовании игнорируется rand. Что можете посоветовать?
Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете перемешивать id используя функцию `shuffle`

```
$array = [6314, 6311, 6308, 6304, 6301, 6297];
shuffle( $array );

$random_post_ids = array_slice( $array, 0, 3 );

$posts = get_posts( ['include' => $random_post_ids ] );
```